# What the best way to truncate encoded URL

Tags: mysql, url

I want to store URL in my MySQL DB. The column type is char(255) - can't get bigger than that without changing the data type.

Since the URL might be longer than 255 characters, I need to cut it before storing in the DB.
The problem is that the URL might be encoded, and I need to understand how to truncate it without damaging the URL when, later, I will want to decode it.

I thought of searching for '%' 4 characters before the 255 character. If it exists, cut from there. If not - cut from the 255 character.

Am I missing something? Is there a better way doing it? Is 4 characters before is enough?

Comment: use compression to store, then decompression when you retrieve

Comment: Can you provide some sample URLs that you are trying to truncate? And the result you expect to be saved to the DB?

Comment: Is changing the datatype out of the question?  You won't be able to truncate and restore an arbitrary URL.

Comment: @MichaelBrewer-Davis Changing datatype is not an option as it will affect the query performance. I prefer truncating the entry point.

Answer (score 3):

If data size is your concern, then your best approach would be to bite the bullet and change your schema to allow more data.

Anything else is just a kludge and will (probably) come back to bite you later.

Comment: Data size is not my concern but performance. Storing the URL as char is ideal for me as I'm indexing this column and performing most of my queries based on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are struggling to fit your URL in 255 char table column then you can consider to use a **URL shortener library** like this: https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/libraries to shorten the URL and then store it.

Answer (score 0):

A good strategy for compressing the URL is to figure out the common parameters / encoding and replace them with a special character/code.  Because the URLs are encoded there are lots of special characters you can safely replace.

Answer (score 0):

Any truncation of a URL is "damaging" to the URL.

Instead of truncating the URL, consider not truncating the URL, but splitting it into multiple rows as needed.

Here is a simple table design for that purpose:

```
NotTruncatedUrl
PK    UrlId                Int
PK    FragmentOrder        Int
NN    Fragment             Varchar(255)
```

Notice the two column pk.
This allows for multiple fragments per url.

just split the URL into fragments of 255 length (the last fragment is likely to be less than 255) and order them using the fragmentOrder.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to do that as it will damage my current query performance.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is -- don't.

That's a really, really bad idea.  You cannot represent a URL in just 255 characters -- URLs can be as big as 2000 or so characters without impacting browser portability.  Limiting them to 255 is a kludge which will damage your data.

Just to sanity check -- have you measured the performance of your query with VARCHAR vs. CHAR(255)?  If you haven't, you might want to; there's a pretty reasonable chance that the modest performance gain you get from a fixed-width type isn't enough to justify a hacky workaround.

Comment: I believe you are saying that as you just didn't actually looked at a 255 characters URL, here it is. Now how much URLs you think that are larger than that? www.something.com/veryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryverylongurl

Comment: Depends on how many query string parameters you're passing.  Form parameters to a GET request get stored in the query string of the URL.    You said yourself that some URLs that are getting stored exceed 255 characters; if you're going to store that data, why would you *not* store any valid URL?